# Use IP tables to port forward behind a router?

Tags: debian, iptables

Is it possible to use IP tables to port forward behind a router?

My setup is thus: I have a Raspberry Pi running a small website on port 80, and a beefier computer running a Minecraft server on port 25565. I've setup the router to take requests for each port and forward them to the correct location, but I also have a Minecraft 'website' (with the map and such) running on the Minecraft server, also on port 80. I also have myurl.com.

My question is: Using IP tables, can I have mc.myurl.com:80 forward to the Minecraft server website, while myurl.com:80 continues to go to the Raspberry Pi? How do I set this up?

What if I remove the Raspberry Pi from the equation? Have mc.myurl.com forward to :81 on the same server? (Would I have to open :81 on the router?)

Comment: Which web server are you using on your Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Apache, but I could easily change that, does it matter?

Comment: Why not look at iptables docs and/or any tutorials first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). Apache can play that [role](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) but I advise you to better use [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) which is lighter.

You will redirect the port `80` to your Raspberry Pi and setup Nginx to proxy the requests for `mc.myurl.com` as following:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mc.myurl.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://my.mine.craft;
  }
}
```

See Nginx's [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the reverse proxy module of Apache2. This will redirect incoming requests by the mc server hostname to another http server, that is located inside your lan. It would be a simpler idea then rely on firewalls.

First, install the module:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-proxy-html
```

Create 2 virtual hosts. One will respond your site requests, and the other will proxy the traffic to your mc site.

```
<VirtualHost YOUR.INTERNET.IP.ADDR:80>
    ServerAdmin me@myurl.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://LAN.IP.YOUR.MC.SITE:PORT/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://LAN.IP.YOUR.MC.SITE:PORT/
    ServerName mc.myurl.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost YOUR.INTERNET.IP.ADDR:80>
  ServerAdmin me@myurl.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/my_site
  ServerName myurl.com
  ErrorLog logs/intranet-error_log
  CustomLog logs/intranet-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

More docs here:

- Apache [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) documentation
- [VirtualHosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) common setups